# "Il n'est de...qu'en" expression?

Tags: expressions, négation

In French "ne" is typically used with "pas." How is the meaning of the sentence changed when "ne" is not used with "pas," but used with "de" instead, as in "Il n'est de charme qu'en toi même" ?

Comment: There's nothing so charming like you. My guess, but I am not a native speaker.

Comment: I'd rather say "There is no charm but inside you".

Comment: THANKS TO THOSE WHO OFFERED TRANSLATIONS! Typically, "ne" in French is used with "pas."  In the line of poetry I quoted, "ne" is used with "de (quelque chose) que" which does not translate literally. I was hoping someone could remind me of what the use of "ne" without "pas" employing "de" instead... means as an expression.

Answer (score 3):

The two-word construct *ne* … *pas* is the “basic” way to form a negation in French. The two-word construct *ne* … *que* is not really a negation: it means “only”. You can see it as a negation meaning “no other than” or “no more than”, but often other languages would not use a negation.

> Je ne peux rester que cinq minutes.   (*I can only stay for five minutes.*)
>   Il n'y a du charme qu'en toi-même.   (*There is charm only in yourself.*)

“*Il n'est de … que …*” is a variant of “*Il n'y a de … que …*” that is no longer used in everyday French or even in typical literary French, but is still fairly common in poetry. In English, you might use a negation and *but* to preserve the poetic phrasing.

> Il n'y a de charme qu'en toi-même.   (*There is no charm but in yourself.*)

Answer (score 1):

This [poem](http://www.lieder.net/lieder/get_text.html?TextId=14994) is using the same pattern multiple time:

> *Il **n'est** de charme **qu**'en toi même*  (There is no charm but in yourself)
> ...
> *Il **n'est** clarté **que** dans tes yeux*  (There is no light but in your eyes)
> ...
> *Il **n'est** blancheur **que** sur ton front*
> ...
> *Il **n'est** ciel pur **que** dans ton cœur*

Prose French would use *il n'y a ... que* instead of *il n'est ... que*

> *Il **n'y a** du charme **qu**'en toi-même* (There is only charm in yourself)
>
> *Il **n'y a** de la clarté **que** dans tes yeux*
>
> ...

One shouldn't confuse ***ne pas*** (not) and ***ne que*** (only):

> *Il n'a pas vingt ans.* -> He is not 20 years old (i.e. he is either younger or older than that).
>
> *Il n'a que vingt ans.* -> He is only 20 years old.